# the meanings of markups in svn merge file

Tags: svn

When I revert back and forth in svn, I got files with markups like this,

```
>>>>>>> .r3

<<<<<<< .mine

||||||| .r11
```

Trying to understand the meanings so I can manually remove the redundant parts.

Answer (score 0):

The markers are described in [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.byhand). However, you don't need to edit them manually. Use some GUI-based conflict resolution tool or built-in CLI conflict resolver. Read [SVNBook | Resolve Any Conflicts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve).

Comment: Thank you! Still can't find "||||||".